# VBS Txt File Variable cant be used

Tags: vbscript

Hey I want to use the date out of a txt file in my VBS script what i gotso far is :

```
Do while not f.AtEndOfLine
Zeile = f.readLine
Feld = split(Zeile,",")
Benutzer = Feld(0)
Gruppe = Feld(1)
Nachname = Feld(2)
Passwort = Feld(3)
ScriptP = Feld(4)
Projekt = Feld(5)
Datum = Feld(6)
Call BenuntzerAnlegen(Benutzer,Gruppe,Nachname,Passwort,ScriptP)
Loop
```

and It works so fat but the date doesn ist written like this:  DD/MM/YYYY in the txt example: AJWKW24Sr1fe,Polo,Rsafa,AMam140981,AJWTN_Logon.cmd,23.06.2016,AJW

I wanted to use it with this :

```
Sub BenuntzerAnlegen (Benutzer,Gruppe,Nachname,Passwort,ScriptP)
Dim ouo, b
Set ouo = GetObject("LDAP://OU=Gruppinsr,DC=ipcenter,DC=local")
Set b = ouo.Create("user", "CN=" & Gruppe & " " & Nachname)
Dim WshShell, ret
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://OU=Gruppinsr,DC=ipcenter,DC=local")


b.Put "sAMAccountName", Benutzer
b.Put "userPrincipalName", Benutzer & "@ipcenter.local"
b.Put "scriptPath", ScriptP
b.SetInfo
b.SetPassword Passwort
b.AccountDisabled = False
b.AccountExpirationDate = Datum
b.SetInfo
```

But it doesnt work it Keep telling me missing string or "types mismatch"

Comment: From where you are getting **`Datum`** in Sub **`BenuntzerAnlegen`** ? Have you created it as global variable?

Comment: In this script parts i posted here are the only BenutzerAnlegen

Call BenuntzerAnlegen(Benutzer,Gruppe,Nachname,Passwort,ScriptP)
Sub BenuntzerAnlegen (Benutzer,Gruppe,Nachname,Passwort,ScriptP)

Comment: Im using a Txt file for the Dates because every User has his own "date" 
`Dim fso, f, Zeile, Feld
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile ("C:\user.txt",1,0)`

Comment: I get that. What I am asking is, you have passed other variable to your sub, but I can't see `Datum` passed, so have you created it as global variable? How `Datum` is getting value?

Comment: Datum should get ist value from the Txt file so Datum = Feld(6) wich is the value after the 6th comma.

Comment: Read my previous comment.

Comment: I dont understand much about Vbs atm i just had to Combine like 2 Diffrent scripts one for Adding users into Active Directory and another for Setting an Expiration Date now as you see im stuck at the date i can set the Date for All but i Need the date Individual like it is in the user.txt file so i Need to get the date into a Var for the VBS wich i can later use for the expiration date.

Answer (score 1):

VBScript date functions ([CDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dt118h2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) (x to Date), [FormatDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aebkz6s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) (Date to String), ...) depend on the regional settings and the locale. This

```
Option Explicit

Dim aD : aD = Split("01.02.2016 2/1/2016")
Dim aL : aL = Split("en-us de_de")
Dim sd, sl, dd, fd, b
For Each sd In aD
    For Each sl in aL
           SetLocale sl
        On Error Resume Next
           dd = CDate(sd)
           If Err.Number Then
              dd = "ERROR " & Err.Number
              fd = dd
              b  = False
           Else
              fd = FormatDateTime(dd)
              b  = (#2/1/2016# = dd)
           End If
        On Error GoTo 0
           WScript.Echo Join(Array(sl, GetLocale, sd, dd, fd, CStr(b)), vbTab)
    Next
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 37968649.vbs
en-us   1033    01.02.2016      ERROR 13        ERROR 13        False
de_de   1031    01.02.2016      01.02.2016      01.02.2016      True
en-us   1033    2/1/2016        2/1/2016        2/1/2016        True
de_de   1031    2/1/2016        02.01.2016      02.01.2016      False
```

proves that CDate fails (often silently) if the input string's format doesn't match the current locale. So calling

```
dtDatum = CDate(Feld(6))
```

while de_de (de-de ?) is active, should give you correct dates for strings in German format.

**P.S.:**

The line

```
b.AccountExpirationDate = Datum
```

'works', because `Datum` is a global variable; so passing it via arguments is a better practice, but doesn't solve the "type mismatch" problem.

**Update wrt comment:**

If your locale is non-german and you feed a german date string like "23.06.2016" to VBScript's date functions, you get an error:

```
>> WScript.Echo GetLocale()
>> d = CDate("23.06.2016")
>>
1033
Error Number:       13
Error Description:  Type mismatch
```

So parse your input file with a german locale.

Alternatively, you could use the amarican format in the file.

Comment: Thx but i dont Understand it :,(

I want that the Date out of the textdocument wich is listed like this :
AJWKW24Sr1fe,Polo,Rsafa,AMam140981,AJWTN_Logon.cmd,23.06.2016,AJW
is used in the VBS file as a Variable or something else so i can use it as expiration date.
Becouse this :  b.AccountExpirationDate = 12/09/2016 works Great but when i try it with a "Datum" it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement clearly, you want the date as **`23/06/2016`** and not as **`23.06.2016`**. If so, just change the line from:

```
Datum = Feld(6)
```

to this:

```
Datum = Replace(Feld(6), ".", "/")
```

And then you need to pass **`Datum`** to your sub that you are calling, like this:

```
Call BenuntzerAnlegen(Benutzer,Gruppe,Nachname,Passwort,ScriptP,Datum)
```

And your Sub should be like this:

```
Sub BenuntzerAnlegen (Benutzer,Gruppe,Nachname,Passwort,ScriptP,Datum)
```

Also, per your example data:

```
AJWKW24Sr1fe,Polo,Rsafa,AMam140981,AJWTN_Logon.cmd,23.06.2016,AJW
```

Datum will be **`Feld(5)`** and not **`Feld(6)`**. So change it.

Comment: I get the error Types Missmatching "cdate"
When I use this: Datum = CDate(Feld(6))

Comment: Can you provide what you'll have in Feld(6). Also it would be great if you can update the question with latest code that you are trying.

Comment: Im still using what I posted above also tried the scripts you guys send me but they didnt work.